# SQL Error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The data going in:

```
<F1>000001234</F1>
<F2>133228579</F2>
<F3>2011-05-25</F3>
<F4>21-332211</F4>
<F5>TxtMail</F5>
<F6/>
<F7>26/04/2011</F7>
<F8>00:09:13</F8>
<F9>0:00</F9>
<F10/>
<F11/>
<F12>Text Service</F12>
<F13>0294443333</F13>
<F14>TXT</F14>
<F15>FR</F15>
<F16>0.17</F16>
```

Relevant parts of the stored procedure :

```
@F1     VARCHAR(24) = NULL, --AccountNumber
@F2     VARCHAR(24) = NULL, --InvoiceNumber
@F3     VARCHAR(24) = NULL, --InvoiceDate
@F4     VARCHAR(24) = NULL, --CallerNumber
@F5     VARCHAR(10) = NULL, --Service
@F6     VARCHAR(10) = NULL, --
@F7     varchar(24) = NULL, --CallDate
@F8     VARCHAR(24) = NULL, --CallTime
@F9     VARCHAR(50) = NULL, --Duration
@F10    VARCHAR(50) = NULL, --
@F11    VARCHAR(10) = NULL, --
@F12    VARCHAR(24) = NULL, --Network
@F13    VARCHAR(24) = NULL, --CallingNumber
@F14    VARCHAR(10) = NULL, --Type
@F15    VARCHAR(10) = NULL, --TypeName
@F16    MONEY       = NULL, --Amount

DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20)
SET @Date = RIGHT(@F7,4)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@F7,4,2)+'/'+LEFT(@F7,2)

-- Combine the date and time into a datetime data type
-- For Time 
DECLARE @time DATETIME
SET @time =  CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date + ' ' + @F8)
```

The error:  The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

This is the only invocation of CONVERT(DATETIME) and I don't use CAST

If I just pass in the data directly, the row gets inserted. If I run the sproc, it goes out-of-range.

Comment: could it be related to your regional setting in SQL server where it's a different format for date than the way you are getting "in the data directly"?

Comment: they are both run on the same computer, and I run the Sproc as a plain SQL query declaring F1-16 and setting values when I 'pass in the data directly'.

But you could be on to something

Comment: I guess I would try passing in the hardcoded date time right into the CONVERT function in a simple sproc just to rule out certain things...then try different formats if one doesn't work.  Just to get down to the bottom of the real issue.

Comment: I just went and tried what you said, stripped everything out except forming the @time, everything else was static values. Still errors. Then i stripped that part out and passed everything in the sproc as static values and the error goes away.

Looks like something definitely is not liking the format being passed in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safe datetime string formats to use in SQL Server is

`YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`.

The conversion you have will fail if [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) is dmy. [SET LANGUAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) will automatically set date format for you. I think both `german` and `norwegian` use dmy.

This will fail:

```
set language norwegian

declare @F7 varchar(10) = '26/04/2011'
declare @F8 varchar(10) = '00:09:13'

DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20)
SET @Date = RIGHT(@F7,4)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@F7,4,2)+'/'+LEFT(@F7,2)

DECLARE @time DATETIME
SET @time =  CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date + ' ' + @F8)
```

Do like this instead (using YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS) to be safe regardless of language/dateformat settings.

```
declare @F7 varchar(10) = '26/04/2011'
declare @F8 varchar(10) = '00:09:13'

DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20)
SET @Date = RIGHT(@F7,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@F7,4,2)+'-'+LEFT(@F7,2)

DECLARE @time DATETIME
SET @time =  CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date + 'T' + @F8)
```

Comment: Yeah SQL doesn't like ddmmyyyy it seems

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see what you are getting,

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(20)
SET @Date = RIGHT('26/04/2011',4)+'/'+SUBSTRING('26/04/2011',4,2)+'/'+LEFT('26/04/2011',2)

-- Combine the date and time into a datetime data type
-- For Time 
DECLARE @time DATETIME
SET @time =  CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date + ' ' + '00:09:13')

print @time
```