# Different results - SQL Server and PHP (PEAR DB)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pear

I'm trying to run a query using php pear db and is not returning any value. However, when I run using SQL Server I get the data

In PHP I'm already setting:

"SET ANSI_NULLS ON" and "SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON"

Query:

`select A.nome, count(sa.id_sala) as Atendimentos, cast( avg( case when (coalesce(sa.dt_final, sa.dt_ping_internauta) > sa.dt_inicio_atendimento) then datediff(minute, coalesce(sa.dt_inicio_atendimento, sa.dt_inicio), coalesce(sa.dt_finalAtendimento, coalesce(sa.dt_final, sa.dt_ping_internauta)) ) else 0 end ) as money) as [media em minutos] from sala SA join atendente A on (A.id_atendente = SA.fk_id_atendente) where sa.interno = 0 and coalesce(sa.dt_inicio_atendimento, sa.dt_inicio) between '2012-01-01' and '2012-12-31' and SA.fk_id_empresa = 1 group by A.nome order by 2 desc`

**SOLVED**

solution:

> "The safe datetime string formats to use in SQL Server is
>
> YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS."

[SQL Error : The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701338/sql-error-the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-result)

Comment: Please add your solution as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

solution:

> "The safe datetime string formats to use in SQL Server is
>
> YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS."

[SQL Error : The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701338/sql-error-the-conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-result)